# Python dice simulation yes or no function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been stuck for days on trying to get the `would you like to reroll die 1-5` yes or no function working as no matter what I type in, it still proceeds to move on and if I put in all Y's, it still gives me the error message of `I'm sorry. Please only enter Y or N.` I think I also need to define the die1-5 = random.randint(1,6) as well, but it doesn't give me the nameError that it's not defined. If there's anything I'm missing, please let me know.

Comment: Use parentheses to group your input checks as needed.  Look up operator precedence for help; it doesn't naturally do what you expect here.  Also, note that you're trying to reroll on any acceptable input, rather than paying attention to what the user gave you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You changed your posting to invalidate the given answers; this is a violation of Stack Overflow practices.  You now ask for help in fixing code you have not posted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0):

None of your if clauses can be true -- they're all equivalent to "did the user say yes and no".  I can't see a reason why the `and keepDieX == 'N' or keepDieX == 'No'` clauses are in there.

Comment: what should I fix that with? I had ```elif keepDie1-5 == 'N':``` on it's own before, but it gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First, get this working first for only a single roll; *then* expand to five dice.

```
if keepDie1[0] in 'Nn':
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
```

should handle your problem well enough; this is what a lot of programs use, only the first letter of the input.  If you want a validity check, then use

```
if keepDie1[0] in "YyNn":
    ...
```

Also note that you converted the input to upper-case, so there's no way it can be "Yes" or "No" when you test it.  See [keep asking until valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for a thorough treatment of the topic.

Finally, I recommend that you check your documentation.  You ask the player if she wants to re-roll each of the dice, but then store those re-roll choices as "keepDie", a name with the opposite semantics.

Comment: Since we no longer know what "it" is, we cannot help.  I made the indicated changes to my copy of your code, and it works as I wrote above.  I suspect that (1) you're still trying to program more than one thing you don't fully understand; (2) you have made one or more of the other logic errors included in your original code, and the combination is your problem.